# Find the constants for the independence of a random variable

Tags: probability

The following is my question:

Let $W(t)$ be a standard Brownian motion, $\xi\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and $\xi$ is independent of $W(t)$ for all $t\geq0$. Define $X(t)=t\xi+\lambda W(t)$, for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $F_t=\sigma(X(s),s\leq t),$ which is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X(s),s\leq t$. For all $t\geq 0$, find the constant $\gamma_t$ such that $Y(t):=\xi-\gamma_t X(t)$ is independent of $F_t.$ And show that $$\lim_{t \rightarrow\infty}E(\xi|F_t)=\xi$$ almost surely.

Assume $\gamma_t$ is found, then $$E(\xi|F_t)=E(Y(t)|F_t)+\gamma_tE(X(t)|F_t)=E(Y(t))+\gamma_tX(t)=E(Y(t))-Y(t)+\xi.$$ It seems like $\gamma_t$ could also be the reason that $E(Y(t))-Y(t)\rightarrow 0$ almost surely, but I don't know how to find the $\gamma_t$ we needed. Thanks for any help.

Comment: To find $\gamma_t$, compute $E(X(t) \cdot Y(t))$ and use the definition of $Y(t)$ and all assumptions. What should be the result if $Y(t)$ is independent of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X(s)_{s \le t}$?

Comment: Thank you so much for this kind hint. I went through the calculations and everything went well, but is it obvious in this case that uncorrelated implies independence? Using they're uncorrelated we get $\gamma_t$, while we still need to say they're independent.

Comment: Remember that these are all Gaussian random variables / processes.